# What is the difference from when you put an element in front of an id or class when declaring it?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering, say you want to define a class or id. What difference does it make when you put an element in front of it? Such as `div.exampleclass { color: red; }` vs just putting `.exampleclass { color: red; }`What is the difference?  As in how does it change the code? Or does it not matter?
I looked around stack overflow and quora, but there weren't any relevant results for this question.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. So is not a forum, tutorial ro guide. It is for coders that can already code and need community debugging help for specific coding issues. It is also expected that you have done sufficient ammount of research and attempted to solve any problem on your own. As such your question not fit for SO.

Comment: It makes the first one override the second

Comment: @AlonEitan That's not strictly accurate. The second selector (with the element-name) does have a _higher specificity_ which means it will override the first selector, but that's not the reason one should simply add an element name to a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without tag selector:** All elements with the class are selected and the css aplleis to all of them

```css
.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">This is a "div" block</div>
<p class="test">This is a paragraph block</p>
```

**With a tag selector:** Only elements with the specific tag are selected and as such the css only applies to them.

```css
div.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">This is a "div" block</div>
<p class="test">This is a paragraph block</p>
```

Comment: To be specific, it isn't called the "tag selector", it's called the _element selector_.

Comment: @Dai that is true. originally I even intended to call it that. However the OP is clearly a beginner and as such I choose a more understandable way for him.

Answer (score 1):

- `div.exampleClass` will match `<div class="exampleClass">`.
- `.exampleClass` will match **any** element with `class="exampleClass"`, such as `<a class="exampleClass anotherClass">`, `<div class="exampleClass">` and `<body class="exampleClass">`.

  - This is the same as `*.exampleClass`, as `*` matches any element as well.